# How do I convert SQL queries to elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are migrating our search app to elastic search from relational database.

We have few SQL queries which are fixed per user preference and want to move them to elastic search query.

Made the design easy by creating an elastic search index same as a single view in our relational database. The json fields are same as that column names in the view.

is they any easy way we can migrate?

Comment: You should check out [this plugin](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql/) and see if it works for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Val This plugin gave me some idea to implement my own solution

Comment: Yes! elasticsearch_sql code is really good. One can convert to a library in case plugin is not needed.

Comment: Try this website: https://www.overvyu.com/sqltoelasticsearch
this might be helpful for you